# Hibernate Data type / updating pojo

Tags: java, hibernate

How can I change this data type from `Date` to `DateTime` :

```
<property name="commentDate" type="date">
        <column name="CommentDate" length="10" not-null="true" />
    </property>
```

Comment: What types are they in the database (and which type of db) and in Java?

Comment: What then do you mean by "change this data type from Date to DateTime" as the mySql is already dateTime